# Animation of progress bar not properly paused

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I created a simple reproduction of my code. Im having an issue with managing an animation of progress bar. The issue is that after pausing an animation you can see the animation goes a little bit backwards and is not being paused in the place it should be when clicking a button. Where is the issue in my code?

And worth mentioning is that its only a reproduction and would be good if class removal is not touched cause in the real code i need to restart the animation on certain condition.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;


const App = () => {
  const totalTime = 10;
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(totalTime);
  const [isTimerAnimated, setIsTimerAnimated] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (timeLeft > 0 && isTimerAnimated) {
        setTimeLeft((prevTimeLeft) => prevTimeLeft - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timeLeft, isTimerAnimated]);

 const handleAnimationState = () => {
    if (isTimerAnimated) {
      setIsTimerAnimated(false);
    } else {
      setIsTimerAnimated(true);
      setTimeLeft(totalTime);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="progress-bar">
        <div
          className={`${isTimerAnimated ? "animated" : ""}`}
          style={{
            transform: `scaleX(${timeLeft ? timeLeft / totalTime : 0})`,
            animationDuration: `${totalTime}s`,
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleAnimationState}>{isTimerAnimated ? "Pause the animation" : "Restart the animation"}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
@keyframes timerAnimation {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #fdb913;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.progress-bar div {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.progress-bar div.animated {
  animation: timerAnimation linear;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be tracking whole seconds with `timeLeft`, but your CSS animation is running smoothly (in milliseconds) when you re-render (on pause) you lose the animation data and use the last `timeLeft` in whole seconds, effectively discarding the progress made in the last fraction of a second.

Comment: Tried with miliseconds but without success unfortunately

Comment: If you want to create smooth JS animations, the best way is to use RequestAnimationFrame, I will add an answer with a demo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 1):

This is a vanilla JS implementation of requestAnimationFrame to show how it can be used to create the desired effect. The browser tries to animate as close as possible to the display refresh rate, as per the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

```js
class AnimatedBar {
  constructor(elem, totalTime){
    this.elem = elem
    this.progressState = 100
    this.currentTime = totalTime
    this.totalTime = totalTime
    this.lastTimeStamp = null
    this.playing = false
    this.animationFrameRequest = null
    
    PlayButton.onclick = () => this.play()
    RestartButton.onclick = () => this.restart()
  }
  pause(){
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationFrameRequest)
    this.playing = false
    this.lastTimeStamp = null
    PlayButton.textContent = 'Play'    
    PlayButton.onclick = () => this.play()
  }
  play(){
    if(this.lastTimeStamp){
      //only change animation state if there is a previous timestamp to go from
      const elapsedTime = Date.now() - this.lastTimeStamp
      this.currentTime -= elapsedTime
      
      if(this.currentTime <= 0){
        this.currentTime = 0
        this.playing = false
        this.lastTimeStamp = null
        
        PlayButton.textContent = 'Restart'        
        PlayButton.onclick = () => this.restart()
      }
      
      this.progressState = (this.currentTime/this.totalTime) * 100
      
      this.elem.style.width = `${this.progressState}%`
    } else {    
      this.playing = true
      PlayButton.textContent = 'Pause'
      PlayButton.onclick = () => this.pause()
    }
    
    this.lastTimeStamp = Date.now()
    
    if(this.playing){
      this.animationFrameRequest = window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.play())
    }
  }
  restart(){
    this.pause()
    this.currentTime = this.totalTime
    this.play()
  }
}


new AnimatedBar(ProgressBar, 10000)
```

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 16px; background: grey; border-radius: 8px; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 8px;">
  <div id="ProgressBar" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: yellow;"></div>
</div>

<button id="PlayButton">Start</button>
<button id="RestartButton">Restart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the timeLeft state to track milliseconds (totalTime * 1000) instead of seconds
I have changed the interval to run every 100 milliseconds (setInterval callback) instead of every second enhances the responsiveness of your progress bar.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const totalTime = 10; // Total time in seconds
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(totalTime * 1000);
  const [isTimerAnimated, setIsTimerAnimated] = useState(true);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (isTimerAnimated && timeLeft > 0) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTimeLeft(prevTimeLeft => prevTimeLeft - 100);
        setProgress(timeLeft / (totalTime * 1000));
      }, 100);
    } else if (timeLeft <= 0) {
      setIsTimerAnimated(false);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timeLeft, isTimerAnimated]);

  const handleAnimationState = () => {
    if (isTimerAnimated) {
      setIsTimerAnimated(false);
    } else {
      setIsTimerAnimated(true);
      setTimeLeft(totalTime * 1000);
      setProgress(1);
    }
  };

  return React.createElement("div", {},
    React.createElement("div", {className: "progress-bar"},
      React.createElement("div", {
        className: "progress",
        style: {
          transform: `scaleX(${progress})`,
        }
      })
    ),
    React.createElement("button", {onClick: handleAnimationState},
      isTimerAnimated ? "Pause the animation" : "Restart the animation"
    )
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
 .progress-bar {
      height: 10px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: #fdb913;
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-top: 2rem;
      margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }

    .progress-bar div {
      background-color: grey;
      height: 100%;
      transform-origin: left center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please include a description of what you have changed, and how it solves the problem.

Comment: The animation is not smooth

Comment: @Adrian to smoothen the animation you can try to add the keyframes back like in your original or you can increase the number of recalculation so it updates more often

Comment: @Adrian I have edited this answer with a smooth version of Jakub's snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, instead of scaling it, you can do its width, which you know will always be between 0 am 100.

Then count your time in milliseconds. So, You can make tiny changes to the progress instead of steps. Then map your time in milliseconds to the progress

```
y(progress) = (x(ms elapsed) / totalTime(s) * 1000 ) * 100
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const totalTime = 4;
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [elapsedMS, setElapsedMS] = useState(0);
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if(!isPaused) {
         setElapsedMS(p => p + 1)
      }
    }, 1)
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
     if(isPaused) setProgress((elapsedMS / (totalTime * 1000)) * 100)
  }, [elapsedMS])

  const handleAnimationState = () => {
    setIsPaused(p => !p)
  }

  

return (
     <div>
        <div className="progress-bar">
           <div
             className={`${isPaused ? "animated" : ""}`}
             style={{
                width: `${100 - progress}%`,
             }}
           />
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleAnimationState}>{isPaused ? "Pause the animation" : "Restart the animation"}</button>
    </div>
  );

};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
@keyframes timerAnimation {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #fdb913;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.progress-bar div {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.progress-bar div.animated {
  animation: timerAnimation linear;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const totalTime = 10;
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(totalTime);
  const [isTimerAnimated, setIsTimerAnimated] = useState(true);
  const barRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (timeLeft > 0 && isTimerAnimated) {
        setTimeLeft((prevTimeLeft) => prevTimeLeft - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timeLeft, isTimerAnimated]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (barRef.current) {
      barRef.current.animate(
        [
          { width: '100%' },
          { width: '0%' }
        ],
        {
          duration: totalTime * 1000,
          fill: 'forwards'
        }
      );
    }
  }, [barRef, totalTime]);

  const handleAnimationState = () => {
    if (isTimerAnimated) {
      barRef.current.getAnimations().forEach(animation => animation.pause());
    } else {
      setTimeLeft(totalTime);
      barRef.current.getAnimations().forEach(animation => animation.play());
    }
    setIsTimerAnimated(!isTimerAnimated);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="progress-bar">
        <div
          ref={barRef}
          className={`${isTimerAnimated ? "animated" : ""}`}
        />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleAnimationState}>{isTimerAnimated ? "Pause the animation" : "Restart the animation"}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #fdb913;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.progress-bar div {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
}

.progress-bar div.animated {
  transition: width 1s linear;
}
```

The issue behind this is the js interval and css transition is not in sync.
But using Web Animations API,it can be easily done.

Things I have changed in code.

1. I am using useRef() to play and pause the animation instead of useState(). It will solve the problem of abrupt animation from going forward while pausing the animation and sync css transition with the js interval.
2. [{ width: '100%' }, { width: '0%' }] - These are the keyframes for the animation. The animation will start with the element's width at 100% and end with the width at 0%.
3. { duration: totalTime * 1000, fill: 'forwards' } - These are the options for the animation. The animation will last for totalTime seconds (converted to milliseconds by multiplying by 1000). The fill: 'forwards' option means that after the animation is finished, the element will retain the style of the last keyframe ({ width: '0%' }).

You can read more about web animation API. [Check this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/play)

I hope this helps! Feel free to ask more about it.